# To save _id without ObjecID part while inserting a new mongo document in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, bson

I noticed, when I insert documents in Meteor, it saves **_id** as `"_id" : "kEdtp42GSupay8tf2"`.

But when I insert using nodejs it saves as `"_id" : ObjectId("55e40c30422ba1aa2906f526")` when using the following code:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:3001/meteor', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var doc = { title: 'post6',
                body: "6 Fake St"
                };

    db.collection('posts').insert(doc, {w:1}, function(err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.dir(doc);

        db.close();
    });
});
```

How should I refactor the code so it insert new `id`s

in the format `"_id" : "kEdtp42GSupay8tf2"`. ?

Comment: Add `_id` to the content in `doc`. You are going to need something that generates one of course. I would not be so keen to move away from the default `ObjectId` though, as unlike what Meteor uses it contains useful things and is also "monotonic" ( or ever increasing ) which the "friendly" formats in meteor are not. You "can" always "train" Meteor to use the `ObjectId` instead. Which is a lot more straightforward than doing it the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer idGeneration option in this link:

```
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection
```

Meteor uses string values for idGeneration. But if you want to change it to default ObjectId generation, then you can set idGeneration option.

Comment: Isn't it possible to save in the format I mentioned in the post?

Comment: In this case, you can specify _id field in  jsondoc  var doc = { _id: "kEdtp42GSupay8tf2", title: 'post6',
                body: "6 Fake St"
                };

Comment: I want to have `_id` auto-generated

Answer (score 1):

You can write a random key generator function and set it to _id.

```
function generateUUID() {
   var d = new Date().getTime(),
     uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx4xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g,
       function(c) {
          var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
          d = Math.floor(d/16);
          return (c==='x' ? r : (r&0x7|0x8)).toString(16);
       });
   return uuid;
}
```

And then use this to set to `_id`.

```
var doc = { title: 'post6',
            body: "6 Fake St"
            _id : generateUUID()};

db.collection('posts').insert(doc, {w:1}, function(err, doc) {
    if(err) throw err;

    console.dir(doc);

    db.close();
});
```